# one column from output column on awk

Tags: command-line, scripts, awk

Suppose which I have this table:

```
one two three four
two three four five
three four five six
four five six seven
five six seven eight
```

so I wrote `awk -v word=two '$0 ~ "[^[:alpha:]]" word "[^[:alpha:]]"'`from [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/349104/awk-match-whole-word/349119#349119) to access all lines which have **two**. and the result is whole of line:

```
one two three four
two three four five
```

If I want to find just $3. what I should add for that command?

If I want to search on the internet to find the answer. what do I should search? Or better to say this easy:( question refer to which topic of AWK?

Comment: Why have you added the link? any why so hidden, make it more easily visible.

Comment: @RegisteredUser I did an update

Comment: I think the command is wrong.

Comment: no I change ABC to two.I wrote wrong but I updated

Comment: How are you using the command, by piping it to `cat` or something OR by providing file on command line OR something else? can you give the whole command?

Comment: I put the table on the file name test. after that I just copy paste the command and I did: awk -v word=two '$0 ~ "[^[:alpha:]]" word "[^[:alpha:]]"' test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15647/discussion-between-registered-user-and-lion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `{print$n}` to print the nth word. So in your case it would be `{print$3}`

The Final command becomes,

```
awk -v word=two '$0 ~ "[^[:alpha:]]" word "[^[:alpha:]]" {print$3}'
```

which will give output

```
three
four
```